# Why do I get duplicate record inserted only at the last record?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I get a duplicate record from my procedure which inserts 330+ records.
But ONLY on the very last record. So in other words the last 2 records are not distinct, they are the same. What is it about this procedure that allows the last record to get duplicated.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `zzExclude_Products` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `zzExclude_Products`()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE VAR_ENTITY_ID VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE CUR_NO CURSOR FOR

SELECT DISTINCT NO
FROM stage_product_data.ITEMMAST AS IM
JOIN stage_product_data.zzLive_Products AS LIVE ON IM.NO = LIVE.SKU
WHERE DIVISION = '30' AND STATUS NOT IN ('XX','YY','ZZ');


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

OPEN CUR_NO;
REPEAT

FETCH CUR_NO INTO VAR_ENTITY_ID;
INSERT INTO zz_CATALOG (TYPE, ENTITY_ID, ESTRICTION_TYPE, RESTRICTION_VALUE)
VALUES ('Product', VAR_ENTITY_ID, 'Country', 'ALL');

UNTIL done END REPEAT;
CLOSE CUR_NO;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need for a cursor here. This can be done in a single INSERT statement.

```
INSERT INTO zz_CATALOG 
    (TYPE, ENTITY_ID, ESTRICTION_TYPE, RESTRICTION_VALUE)
    SELECT DISTINCT 'Product', EDPNO, 'Country', 'ALL'
        FROM stage_product_data.ITEMMAST AS IM
            JOIN stage_product_data.zzLive_Products AS LIVE 
                ON IM.EDPNO = LIVE.SKU
        WHERE DIVISION = '30' 
            AND STATUS NOT IN ('XX','YY','ZZ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is the procedure and not duplicates in the data you are inserting?

Comment: thanks I checked that and I don't have a dupe in the lookup table.